# Nodejs - Passport-saml implementation with One-login

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, saml, onelogin

I'm trying to run below `passport-sample` example with one login SSO. But I couldn't make it successful. I have given `Onelogin HTTP-redirect` url in the SAML entry point(`config.js`). It was redirecting to one login authentication page and redirecting back to application page but the application is not loading.

https://github.com/gbraad/passport-saml-example

Please advise what am I missing here.

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    app: {
      name: 'Passport SAML strategy example',
      port: process.env.PORT || 3000
    },
    passport: {
      strategy: 'saml',
      saml: {
        path: process.env.SAML_PATH || '/login/callback',
        entryPoint: process.env.SAML_ENTRY_POINT || 'https://domain.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/200908',
        issuer: 'passport-saml',
        cert: process.env.SAML_CERT || null
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The saml `entryPoint` doesn't look right in the passport saml configuration.

It is currently configured to the **single logout service URL**; whereas

the **single sign on service URL** should read similar to:

```
'https://domain.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/200908'
```

The protocol binding used in entry point above is also ascertained to be the right one because the `AuthNRequest` sent in [`passport-saml` module at version `0.5.0`](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml/blob/v0.5.0/lib/passport-saml/saml.js#L105) uses `http-post` protocol binding for the authentication request with the identity provider and not `http-redirect` protocol binding.